# Test equality of binomial variances across four groups

Tags: hypothesis-testing, anova, binomial-distribution, binary-data, levenes-test

I have four 100x1 vectors of binary outcomes of a particular experiment. I want to test for equality in variance across all of the four different treatment groups.

At the moment I have used the Levene test http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levene%27s_test to do this. However, I wanted to check whether this is a reasonable thing to do when dealing with binary data?

Best,

Ben

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variance of a Bernoulli random variable (the 0/1 binaries you have in each group) depends on the proportion - if the proportions differ, then so will the variance.

You should not expect equality of variance. It's a waste of time to test for it.

You can do tests for differences in binomial proportions which properly account for this.

1) A test for homogeneity of proportion. This is a straight 2x4 chi-square.

2) a binomial glm with group as a factor variable. This would give you an asymptotic likelihood ratio test (this should be equivalent to the [G-test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G-test)).

The two tests should generally give similar results in large samples.